# How to create a new line when text overflows row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, holder.js

When creating a new img holder:

```
<img src="holder.js/200x75/industrial/text:this text is too long for only one row">
```

There is no enough space in one row to hold the text, and I can't get a hold of how to do break for new line.

Does anyone have an idea?

thanks

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? Need to see what kind of structure you have around you img.

Comment: Linebreaks will be added in the 2.4 release.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks are now added: https://github.com/imsky/holder#text

```
<img data-src="holder.js/300x200?text=Add \n line breaks \n anywhere.">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax and settings. Or try to update the [Holder.js](http://holderjs.com/).

> Holder [automatically adds](https://github.com/imsky/holder#text) line breaks to text that goes outside of the
>   image boundaries.

This code works as it should:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/imsky/holder/master/holder.js"></script>

<img src="holder.js/200x75/industrial?text=this text is too long for only one row">
```